I'm having problems with the tailwind of my project
I made a copy of Instagram using tailwind, however tailwind works everywhere on the page, except for one image (main image), and even on other images it is working and as I am a beginner I was unable to solve this problem.
I tried the following code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="./output.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Tailwind</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="h-screen w-screen grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 grid-rows-6">

      <!-- Main image-->
      <div class="row-span-5 md:flex justify-end hidden">
        <img class="max-w-96" src="./img/insta-img (1).png"/>
      </div>

      <!-- Form-->

      <div class="row-span-5 flex flex-col justify-center items-center grid-cols-1">
        <form class="w-80 flex flex-col justify-center items-center border rounded-sm px-10 py-4 gap-5 ">
          <img class="w-52" src="./img/insta-logo.png" alt="insta-logo" />

          <input class="bg-slate-50 h-9 w-full pl-3 border rounded-sm " type="text" placeholder="Phone Number, username, e-mail" />
          <input class="bg-slate-50 h-9 w-full pl-3 border rounded-sm " type="password" placeholder="Password"/>

          <button class="bg-blue-400 w-full rounded-md h-8 text-slate-50 hover:bg-slate-300">Entrar</button>

          <a class="text-blue-800 font-bold cursor-pointer" href="#">Log in with Facebook</a>
          <a class="text-blue-800 text-sm cursor-pointer" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
        </form>

        <div class="border w-80 my-4 text-center py-4">
          <p>Don't have an account?<a class="text-blue-400 font-bold" href="#"> Sign up</a></p>
        </div>

        <p>Get the app</p>

        <div class="flex gap-2 mt-4">
          <img class="h-10" src="./img/microsoft.png" alt="microsoft" />
          <img class="h-10" src="./img/google.png" alt="google" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- footer -->

      <footer class="row-span-1 col-span-2">
        <ul class="flex flex-wrap gap-5 justify-center">
          <li class="text-slate-800 text-sm">Meta</li>
          <li class="text-slate-800 text-sm">About</li>
          <li class="text-slate-800 text-sm">Blog</li>
          <li class="text-slate-800 text-sm">Jobs</li>
          <li class="text-slate-800 text-sm">Help</li>
          <li class="text-slate-800 text-sm">API</li>
          <li class="text-slate-800 text-sm">Privacy</li>
          <li class="text-slate-800 text-sm">Terms</li>
          <li class="text-slate-800 text-sm">Locations</li>
          <li class="text-slate-800 text-sm">Instagram Lite</li>
          <li class="text-slate-800 text-sm">Threads</li>
          <li class="text-slate-800 text-sm">Contact Uploading & Non-Users</li>
          <li>Meta Verified</li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="flex flex-wrap gap-5 justify-center mt-6">
          <li class="text-slate-800">English</li>
          <li class="text-slate-800">© 2024 Instagram from Meta</li>
        </ul>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

and the result was this: image of how it turned out

What exactly do you want to achieve here? If the issue is the size of the image then, you should just pass the w-96 instead of max-w-96

Well, even though I changing the max-w-96 to w-96 only the size changes, the other functions like the hidden are not working.

It's working fine when I tried to reproduce the issue, what installation of tailwind did you follow?

I used the one in the official Tailwind documentation. My tailwind.config.js is apparently right according to the documentation, my suspicion is that there is something wrong with the output.css but I don't know how to verify this suspicion.

Kindly provide more info, what framework are you using, share your tailwind.config,js, will provide us with more context to what is actually happening

Right, the desired behavior is that on smaller screens, the form takes up all the space, and on larger screens, an image appears next to the form. The image should be hidden on small screens and appear on medium and larger screens.
I'm encountering problems on smaller screens, the image doesn't disappear when I use Hidden and on larger screens it doesn't stay next to the form.   My config.js is: /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} /
module.exports = {
content: ["./src/**/.{html,js}"],
theme: {
extend: {},
},
plugins: [],
}

code works as expected, one larger screen image is coming to the left of the form and on smaller screens it disappears, can you show how the mobile view looks for you? What browser are you using?

Hello, I managed to fix it, thanks to the lord and some friends, the problem was in my output.css and now it is working normally. I thank you very much for helping me.
